# Autofac register class

Tags: c#, autofac

I have a class  which has a dependency on logger. How can register to make sure logger is pass?

```
public class Files : IHttpHandler
{

    public Files(ILogger logger)
    {
        Logger = logger;
        fileService = new FileService(logger);
    }    
}
```

Comment: What [have you tried](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) thus far? What [research](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/) have you done?

Answer (score 0):

It is not a big deal, if you don't have some another pitfals. Please consder the example below:

```
[Test]
public void PassLoggerToHandlersCtor()
{
    // Arrange
    var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
    builder.RegisterType<Logger>().As<ILogger>();
    builder.RegisterType<Files>().As<IHttpHandler>();
    builder.RegisterType<FileService>().AsSelf();
    var container = builder.Build();

    // Act
    var handler = container.Resolve<IHttpHandler>();

    // Assert
    Assert.IsInstanceOf<Files>(handler);
    var files = (Files) handler;
    Assert.IsInstanceOf<Logger>(files.Logger);
    Assert.IsInstanceOf<Logger>(files.fileService.Logger);

}

public class Files : IHttpHandler
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Just for tests
    /// </summary>
    public ILogger Logger { get; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Just for tests
    /// </summary>
    public FileService fileService { get; }


    /// <inheritdoc />
    public bool IsReusable { get; }

    public Files(ILogger logger)
    {
        Logger = logger;
        fileService = new FileService(logger);
    }

    /// <inheritdoc />
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {

    }
}

public interface ILogger { }

public class Logger : ILogger { }

public class FileService
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Just for tests
    /// </summary>
    public ILogger Logger { get; }

    public FileService(Program.ILogger logger)
    {
        Logger = logger;
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.